# InApp purchase feature Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm currently developing a Windows 8.1 application (Store app). When I submitted it for certification on the Windows Store, my application has been refused and I'm sure this is because of in-app purchase feature.

In debug mode, I've tested the in-app purchase feature thanks to the WindowsStoreProxy.xml file and everything was working well. I've also thought to modify the reference of the "currentApp" variable before submitting. (CurrentApp instead of CurrentAppSimulator).

I also referenced my items in the "Services" category onto the Windows Store dashboard.

I implemented the in-app purchase feature following this project: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a

I don't have any explicit error message while my app is refused for submitting on the Windows Store. I'm feeling that when my app is tested by Microsoft, it crashes because it has not been published on the Store yet, so my items are not yet "initialized".

Here is a code sample:

```
var currentApp = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp;

currentApp.loadListingInformationAsync().done(    function (listing) {       

var item1 = listing.productListings.lookup("Item1");       

var item2 = listing.productListings.lookup("Item2");       

var item3 = listing.productListings.lookup("Item3");       

var item4 = listing.productListings.lookup("Item4");
```

Any idea please ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to add some logging to your app to catch unhandled exceptions?

Comment: That's a good idea. loadListingInformationAsync will throw if you're offline or the information isn't available. Should definitely have an error handler passed to .done and fail gracefully if your in-app products aren't available. It's possible that the manual testing step for Store cert does an offline test.